# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function with Apify Metamorph

Tags: apify

I am trying to get my hands on Apify's [Actor Metamorph](https://apify.com/docs/actor#metamorph) with a very simple example :

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const request = require('request-promise');

Apify.main(async () => {

    const newInput = {
        startUrls: [{url: "http://example.org"}],
        pageFunction: () => {
            const title = await page.title();
            console.log(title);
        }
    };

    await Apify.metamorph('apify/web-scraper', newInput);

});
```

However the run fails with a syntax error :

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

How do I pass the `async` nature of `pageFunction` to the `apify/web-scraper` through Metamorph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `async` keyword in front of the function:

```
pageFunction: async () => {
    const title = await page.title();
    console.log(title);
}
```